# Using implicit differentiation, find $\dfrac {dy}{dx}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

Using implicit differentiation, find $\dfrac {dy}{dx}$
$$x^3y^6=(x+y)^9$$

My Attempt:
$$x^3y^6=(x+y)^9$$
Differentiating both sides with respect to $x$, we get:
$$\dfrac {d}{dx} (x^3y^6)=\dfrac {d}{dx} ((x+y)^9)$$
$$x^3.\dfrac {d}{dx} y^6 + y^6. \dfrac {d}{dx} x^3=9(x+y)^8 \dfrac {d}{dx} (x+y)$$
$$6x^3y^5.\dfrac {dy}{dx} + 3x^2y^6 = 9(x+y)^8 (1+\dfrac {dy}{dx})$$
$$\dfrac {dy}{dx}=\dfrac {9(x+y)^8-3x^2y}{6x^3y^5-9(x+y)^8}$$

But the answer is $$\dfrac {dy}{dx}=\dfrac {y}{x}$$...

Comment: If we are talking real numbers, then you could take the cube root of $x^3y^6=(x+y)^9$ first to get $xy^2=(x+y)^3$. Also, I might be missing something, but where did all the powers of $y$ go? $y$ has a higher exponent than $x$ in all the $xy$ terms, except in your final expression. Have they been simplified away somehow?

Comment: @Arthur Your idea of taking cube roots turned out to be very useful in getting to the final simple form that the OP required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed a typo in your question, and with that, your implicit differentiation is perfectly correct. However, it looks difficult (as in, I cannot see how) to reduce it from that to the expected simple answer.

However, following @Arthur's hint, if you're dealing only with the real domain it makes things a lot easier to take cube roots right at the outset. This simplifies things greatly.

$x^3y^6 = (x+y)^9$

For $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$,

$xy^2 = (x+y)^3$

Differentiating implictly wrt $x$,

$y^2 + 2yy'x = 3(x+y)^2(1+y')$

$y'(2yx-3(x+y)^2) = 3(x+y)^2 - y^2$

$\displaystyle y' = \frac{3(x+y)^2 - y^2}{2yx-3(x+y)^2}$

Use the initial relationship given on the RHS,

$\displaystyle y' = \frac{\frac{3(x+y)^3}{x+y} - y^2}{2yx-\frac{3(x+y)^3}{x+y}}$

$\displaystyle y' = \frac{\frac{3xy^2}{x+y} - y^2}{2yx-\frac{3xy^2}{x+y}}$

The rest is just algebra,

$\displaystyle y' = \frac{3xy^2 - y^2(x+y)}{2yx(x+y)-3xy^2}$

$\displaystyle y' = \frac{3xy^2 - xy^2 - y^3}{2yx^2 + 2y^2x-3xy^2}$

$\displaystyle y' = \frac{2xy^2 - y^3}{2yx^2 - xy^2}$

$\displaystyle y' = \frac{y^2(2x - y)}{yx(2x - y)}$

$\displaystyle y' = \frac yx$

as required, et voilà!

EDIT: And just to flesh out @lab's excellent hint involving logarithmic differentiation:

$3 \log x + 6\log y = 9\log(x+y)$

$\displaystyle \frac 3x + \frac 6y y'= \frac 9{x+y}(1+y')$

$\displaystyle y'(\frac 6y - \frac 9{x+y}) = \frac 9{x+y} - \frac 3x$

$\displaystyle y'(\frac{6x-3y}{y(x+y)}) = \frac{6x-3y}{x(x+y)}$

$\displaystyle y' = \frac yx$

A decidedly much quicker route to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

For $$(x+y)^{m+n}=x^my^n$$

Take logarithm wrt base $e,$

$$(m+n)\ln(x+y)=m\ln x+n\ln y$$

Now differentiate wrt $x$

Comment: A much neater and more elegant solution than my original purely algebraic one. Upvoting.